# SQLite query to determine first 6 winning lotto numbers

Tags: sqlite

So the database is this:

```
CREATE TABLE Combination
(combinationNo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
N1 INTEGER NOT NULL,
N2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
N3 INTEGER NOT NULL,
N4 INTEGER NOT NULL,
N5 INTEGER NOT NULL,
N6 INTEGER NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (N1, N2, N3, N4, N5, N6)
);
CREATE TABLE Draw
(drawNo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
drawDate DATE NOT NULL,
drawName TEXT,
winCombinationNo INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY (winCombinationNo) REFERENCES Combination (combinationNo)
);
CREATE TABLE Ticket
(ticketNo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
drawNo INTEGER NOT NULL,
soldAt TEXT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (drawNo) REFERENCES Draw (drawNo)
);
CREATE TABLE Line
(ticketNo INTEGER NOT NULL,
lineID TEXT NOT NULL,
combinationNo INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ticketNo, lineID),
FOREIGN KEY (ticketNo) REFERENCES Ticket (ticketNo),
FOREIGN KEY (combinationNo) REFERENCES Combination (combinationNo)
);
```

I do see

```
FOREIGN KEY (winCombinationNo) REFERENCES Combination (combinationNo)
```

But I only have this so far:

```
SELECT combinationNo
FROM Combination
WHERE
LIMIT 6;
```

I know I need to use a join somewhere but I don't know which one to use, where or how.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do something like :-

```
WITH 
    drawNumber AS (SELECT 2 /*<<<<<<<<<< The drawNo  */),
    winningNumbers(wn) AS 
        (
            SELECT n1||','||n2||','||n3||','||n4||','||n5||','||n6 FROM Draw JOIN Combination ON Draw.winCombinationNo = Combination.combinationNo WHERE Draw.drawNo = (SELECT * FROM drawNumber)
        )
SELECT 
    Ticket.ticketNo AS TicketNo, 
    Line.LineId, 
    n1||' '||n2||' '||n3||' '||n4||' '||n5||' '||n6 AS Entry,
    (SELECT * FROM winningNumbers) AS WinningNumbers,
    (instr((SELECT ','||wn||',' FROM winningNumbers),','||n1||',') > 0) +
    (instr((SELECT ','||wn||',' FROM winningNumbers),','||n2||',') > 0) +
    (instr((SELECT ','||wn||',' FROM winningNumbers),','||n3||',') > 0) +
    (instr((SELECT ','||wn||',' FROM winningNumbers),','||n4||',') > 0) +
    (instr((SELECT ','||wn||',' FROM winningNumbers),','||n5||',') > 0) +
    (instr((SELECT ','||wn||',' FROM winningNumbers),','||n6||',') > 0)
    AS score
FROM Line 
    JOIN Combination ON Line.CombinationNo = Combination.combinationNo
    JOIN Ticket ON Ticket.ticketNo = Line.TicketNo
WHERE score > 0 AND DrawNo = (SELECT * FROM drawNumber)
ORDER BY score DESC 
LIMIT 6
;
```

This would produce results like :-

[image]

- Note that due to the lack of information provided the winning determination may by different to what may have been anticipated.

The above was based upon the random generation of up to 100000 combinations (reduced by removing combinations of the same numbers) and the generation of 20000 tickets each with a single line with 4 draws (drawNo's 1-4).

If accumulation of lines scores was to be taken into consideration then it would simply be a matter of grouping by score and retrieving the sum of the scores.

Comment: Is there no way for the query to be smaller? This is part of a past exam and worth only 4 marks, surely they don't expect it to be that long? I greatly appreciate the help though

Comment: @ChetanTakyar **IF** the numbers (combinations) had to be in order according to the size of the value then direct comparisons could be made to ascertain the score, which would reduce the size by eliminating the need to generate the string of values and the need to use the instr function. Of course the above would cope with scenario.